# x86 movzx instruction -- clarification requested

Tags: assembly, x86

There are two instructions that I ran into today which occur in a form that I am not familiar with:

```
movzx   eax,byte ptr MODULE!My_Function+0xcd4 (00692e84)[eax]
jmp     dword ptr Module!My_Function+0xc7c (00692e2c)[eax*4]
```

I understand it wants to move a byte and zero extend it in eax but what are those square brackets at the end of these instructions?

Comment: Is this disassembler output? Can you show me the machine code for these functions?

Comment: Those are just your normal effective address syntax. The only complication is your friendly disassembler inserting symbols and values. The actual code reads `movzx eax, byte ptr [00692e84 + eax]`. The disassembler thought you might want to know that `00692e84` is near to the symbol `MODULE!My_Function`, offset by `0xcd4`.

Comment: @Jester I guessed it has to be an effective address but I wanted to make sure. In my context its still not making sense. `dds 00692e84 + eax l1` seems to contain what looks like the address of another function. I am unsure what that means. (I forgot to mention I am using Windbg to spelunk into this.)

Comment: We can't tell what exactly that means from this much information. The value loaded into `eax` is an index into a jump table, it's not expected to be an address.

Comment: @Jester You are right. It is my problem at this point but thanks for confirming my original question!